# What do you do when ember-cli rimraf node_module requires glob and returns 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

While attempting to migrate ember apps to ember-cli rather than grunt-cli, HTMLBars rather than handlebars and history API rather than hashchange, my new test projects got a 'undefined is not a function' due to the rimraf module now requiring glob and some problem in using that.

I still had a working project where ember-cli node_modules have the older rimraf so I replaced the CLI node_modules with the older ones and was able to get test projects running again. I'm still using ember-cli 0.2.0-beta.1 because 0.2.0 caused me other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with dependencies being out of line was probably temporary since revisions within CLI are happening so fast. If I came back the next day and cleared out module and component cache and started over, it probably would have cleared up. By reverting CLI manually I wound up with other issues with express live update, so would have to stop and restart express after every edit. I realized I wasn't ready to re-write my gruntfile as a brocfile and deal with all the other issues with migrating to Ember CLI, so started over by updating the Ember dependency in my grunt-based project and going that route, which is also frustrating and hugely problematic, but I'm sure I'm farther along in this route than I would have been in re-writing for Ember CLI.